# JSF select Primefaces selectOneMenu inside dialog hiding menu option z-index

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu, primefaces

View:

```
<p:dialog header="Search in code tables" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="true">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="tableId" value="#{xxx.tableId}"
                        required="true" label="tableId">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{xxx.tables}" ></f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The z-index for the dialog causes the menu options to hide behind it.

I am following standard example from Primefaces showcase:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/loginDemo.xhtml

This appears to be a know n issue 
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33972

Can someone suggest a proper fix.

Comment: Which Version of Primefaces are you using? Are you providing any `z-index` from css explicitly? Is your `p:dialog` inside any component with relative positioning (like `div` or container or table) ?

Answer (score 4):

okay I have managed to figure this out.

I was missing a appendTo telling which component to append the select:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tableId" value="#{xxx.tableId}"
            required="true" label="tableId" appendTo="@this" >
```

This fixes the z-index as well as adding a scrollbar to the drop down.

I have not been able to find this anywhere so posting this self answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `panelStyle` for `selectOneMenu`.
Using `appendTo = "@this"` may cause something like this:
[image: hiding dropDown]
You could use `panelStyle = "position:fixed"` instead.
Regards.