# How to display properly a drop downlist of checkboxes in an cellEdit tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I've got a problem for displaying this dropdown list of booleans in an editCell, i'm using PrimeFaces dataTable.

```
<p:column 
headerText="#{ListPartSalesViewBean.listColumnToDisplay[33].label}"
rendered="#{ListPartSalesViewBean.listColumnToDisplay[33].isDisplayed}"
width="200">
<p:cellEditor>  
    <f:facet name="output">
        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="basic" value="#{opcs.manualChangeComment}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{opcs.manualChangeComment}" var="mcc" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{mcc.isChecked}" itemDisabled="true"/>
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>
    </f:facet>  
    <f:facet name="input"> 
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{opcs.manualChangeComment}" filter="false" label="Choix cause" panelStyleClass="manual-change-comment">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{opcs.manualChangeComment}" var="mcc" itemLabel="#{mcc.label}" itemValue="#{mcc.isChecked}"/>  
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>  
    </f:facet>  
</p:cellEditor>
```

It looks like this for now, i'd like something "simple", any idea?

[screen of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxR6u.png)

Comment: Look at the 'appendTo' attribute of the select. Populate it with '@this'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431238/jsf-select-primefaces-selectonemenu-inside-dialog-hiding-menu-option-z-index (it is sort of a duplicate but not directly). But you might need to play with overflow to. All html/css related

Comment: Populating with "@this" kinda works because the select menu is now stuck to the button so it's good. But it stays "into" the cell so we don't see it as the cell doesn't expand. How could it be just over the cells below, like a dropdownlist would do? Thanks already :)

Comment: that is why mentioned overflow... the css thing..

Comment: yep i read :) but i see in css that z-index is at 1001 (don't know why...) and still not in the first plan. So it's stuck in the cell which is weird. What do you think?

Comment: Overflow != z-index

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was actually deeper than i thought but here is my solution.

To load JQuery use the primefaces library

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
```

instead of the "usual"

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />
```

no need then to manipulate overflow or z-index or anything else

Comment: There is no need to manually include jquery. It is done automagically. And if next time you created a [mcve] you'd either habe directly found this or we could have pointed you to this error. But great it works!